# Marklogic Query to fetch all the documents present in database

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I want to know the query to fetch all the documents present in database. I am aware of the query which will fetch the documents present under a particular folder. Below is the example for the same(getting count).

```
fn.count(xdmp.directory(["/dir1/"],"1"));
```

But I want to know how to fetch all documents in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to count all of the documents:

```
fn.count(fn.doc())
```

Or you could use [cts.estimate()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.estimate) for a fast estimate of a search for document fragments:

```
cts.estimate(cts.trueQuery(), 'document')
```

Applying that criteria to [`cts.search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search):

```
cts.search(cts.trueQuery(), 'document')
```